# Symfony2 main request object in partial controller

Tags: symfony

I use twig render and in partial controller I want get main controller name, but

```
$this->get('request')->get('_template')->get('controller')
```

return `partial`.

How I can get main request object in partial controller?

Now I use:

```
{% render 'FooBundle::Controller:action' with {'controller': getControllerName()  } %}
```

with custom Twig function.
Maybe there are more elegant ways to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to explicitly pass this value in the render tag.

```
{% render 'AcmeBundle:Demo:something' with { 'via': app.request.attributes.get('_controller') } %}
```

Answer (score 2):

What you probably need is the `include` tag which includes another template.

```
{% include 'FooBundle::partial.html.twig' %}
```

Template inclusion is for simple cases, where you just need things like partials.

The `render` tag is for invoking controllers, doing more complex things, or if your template can't access the variables needed to display easily. Doing that the kernel creates a new request as if it came as a standalone request. In fact using ESI it could be a standalone request to that controller.[See here for details](http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/http_cache.html#using-esi-in-symfony2). Because of that, you can't get the main request object, there is probably no main request object because you use ESI or because you create a route for that controller and invoke it via AJAX or whatever. Relying on the the information that your controller is invoked via a sub-request is not supported by the framework as I know, and I think it's intentional. You have to pass all information in query parameters.

Your example isn't correct, it would be like this:

```
{% render 'FooBundle:MyController:actionName' ... %}
```

You have to have a `FooBundle\Controller\MyControllerController` class like this for tihs to work.

```
namespace FooBundle\Controller;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyControllerController extends Controller {
    public function actionNameAction() {
    ...
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I mistaken in render example and fixed this. But my question is open :)
How I can in "FooBundle:MyController:actionName" get main request object?

Comment: You can't as I know. I added a sentence to my answer about why you can't.

Comment: I added more details as of How I did it.

Comment: @renoirb: That's not how Stack Overflow works. You don't just hijack someone else's answer and stick a bunch of your own code in it. If you think you have a better answer, then post it as a *separate* answer. You don't change someone else's answer to be yours.

Comment: I thought it could have had been useful, I felt the example was incomplete. Ok. sorry for that.